# TreeView Text Length Node truncate

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i wondering if it's possible to increase the length of text node in a treeview

I got a json file transformed to a treeview but i have a field called Description how is pretty long and get truncated in the Text field of the node.

Edit: i Edit the field in the tree view to transform it back to json

Image
[image]

Comment: The Node's Tooltip can show the node Text in multiple lines, if you have line breaks in there (either `\n` or `\r\n`). It's also probably more *easy on the eyes* (well, it's an old control) than a, potentially, 32k pixels wide TreeView. You can always owner-draw it instead. Or get one that already implements this feature.

Comment: I got some \n in the filed but don't go to next line, see the picture too  "value":"<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.<\/li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.<\/li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.<\/li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".<\/li>\n<\/ul>"

Comment: It's the Node's ToolTip that can show text in multiple lines, not the Node itself. You have to set `TreeView.SetNodeToolTips = true;`. The ToolTip takes the text from the Node, you don't have to do anything to show it, just enable this feature.

Comment: Thank you i set TreeView.SetNodeToolTips = true but stills truncate the text after the \n

Comment: Don't put the "data" in the node's Text property.  Just put the representative text in there for visual purposes.  Link the node key to where all your data is.

Comment: The hard upper limit is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvitemw).

Comment: It worked like a tooltip, but i forgot to say i need to edit the field, because i transform  it that back to a json

Comment: Then you probably don't want to edit that kind of text in a Node. Bind your *class model* (whatever you call it) that deserialized the JSON to some Controls and the TreeNodes, so when you move to a different Node you also move the `CurrencyManager.Current` value and the edited text will apply to the current property value of the JSON structure. If you use a BindingSource you can also see the edit change the text in real time in more than one bound Control.